# Changing text depending on background.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, colors

So I have a page where the color changes dynamically. And so will the text. Here's what I'm using.

`if (parseInt(color, 16) > 0xffffff / 2) {}`

The problem is that the code isn't applying to `000000`, so when I enter that in the hex box, the text stays black, making it unreadable. [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/2kRe2/) a demo

Comment: Its working fine on changing value background color is also changing.

Comment: The background is changing. Not the text.... That's what to code does, if you were to review it. @Akhlesh

Comment: I have given my answer. Check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text remains black because you don't actually change text color in the method you specify.

This, is incorrect because you have text in the middle of nowhere (and missing a semi-colon, if it were valid to begin with):

```
if(parseInt(color, 16) > 0xffffff/2)
{'black'
} else {
  'white';
}
```

To make this do something, I changed it to:

```
function updateTextColors(color) {
    //CHANGE TEXT COLOR
    if(parseInt(color, 16) > 0xffffff/2)
    {
        $("body").css('color', 'black');
    } else {
        $("body").css('color', 'white');
    }
}
```

Note that made use of jQuery for the sample, for the simplicity of showing you. You can then call this method with the color and will adjust appropriately.

http://jsfiddle.net/YLeZC/3/

PS. While not in the scope of your question, you'll want to make sure to prevent invalid hex colors from causing a text color update as well as add better support for 3 digit hex codes.

Answer (score 1):

isDark method is not giving correct result you can use another function to check color.

```
var getRGB = function (b) {
  var a;
  if (b && b.constructor == Array && b.length == 3) return b;
  if (a = /rgb\(\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*,\s*([0-9]{1,3})\s*\)/.exec(b)) return [parseInt(a[1]), parseInt(a[2]), parseInt(a[3])];
  if (a = /rgb\(\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*,\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*,\s*([0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?)\%\s*\)/.exec(b)) return [parseFloat(a[1]) * 2.55, parseFloat(a[2]) * 2.55, parseFloat(a[3]) * 2.55];
  if (a = /#([a-fA-F0-9]{2})([a-fA-F0-9]{2})([a-fA-F0-9]{2})/.exec(b)) return [parseInt(a[1], 16), parseInt(a[2], 16), parseInt(a[3],
16)];
  if (a = /#([a-fA-F0-9])([a-fA-F0-9])([a-fA-F0-9])/.exec(b)) return [parseInt(a[1] + a[1], 16), parseInt(a[2] + a[2], 16), parseInt(a[3] + a[3], 16)];
return (typeof (colors) != "undefined") ? colors[jQuery.trim(b).toLowerCase()] : null
};

var isDark = function (color) {
  var rgb = getRGB(color);
  if (!rgb) return null;
  return (0.2126 * rgb[0] + 0.7152 * rgb[1] + 0.0722 * rgb[2]) > 180 ? false : true;
}
```

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WzLf8/3/)

Comment: Can you supply a demo? It doesn't seem to be chaining the color.

Answer (score 0):

You have added a property to change background color but not the text color. I've added an extra line your code.

`document.body.style.color = "#" + txt_color;`

Hope this is what you need.
http://jsbin.com/jilibabi/2

Comment: I was trying to only do black and white for the text color.... It's in my code, but I should of mentioned it in the post. Sorry .

Comment: you want to generate a black or white color for text randomly?

Comment: No. Black or white depending on the background. So if I get a dark background, i'll get light text. And the same way around

Comment: So, you need check if it is dark or light background first. Here's how it is done.

`      //CHANGE TEXT COLOR
if(parseInt(color, 16) > 0xffffff/2) {
  document.body.style.color='black';
} else {
  document.body.style.color='white';
}`

Demo: http://jsbin.com/jilibabi/4

Comment: No, It is black. where did you change it to `fffff`?

Comment: Ok. So, the problem is with black. I've edited the code. Should work fine now.

http://jsbin.com/jilibabi/5

Comment: But now when I do `000000`, the text is black.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed and cleaned your code: [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2kRe2/3/)

```
// Current color
var cColor = {};

function setColor(color, dontUpdate) {
    //Change BG color 
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#" + color;

    //Change text color
    document.body.style.color =
        parseInt(color, 16) > 0xffffff/2
    ? 'black'
    : 'white';

    // Update HEX field
    $('.hex').val(color);

    // Only update RGB fields if needed    
    if(!dontUpdate) {
        $('.r').val(parseInt(cColor.r = color.substr(0,2), 16));
        $('.g').val(parseInt(cColor.g = color.substr(2,2), 16));
        $('.b').val(parseInt(cColor.b = color.substr(4,2), 16)); 
    }
}

// Listen to space key
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == '32') {
        // Generate random HEX color
        setColor(Math.random().toString(16).slice(2, 8));
    }
});

// Listen to changes in fields. Consider using "input" event instead
// of "keyup" to detect changes no produced by keyboard, e.g. pasting.
// It won't work on IE8, though.

// Change BG on input on HEX       
$('.hex').on('keyup', function () {
    setColor($(this).val());
});

// Change BG on input on RGB
$('.r, .g, .b').on('keyup', function() {
    var primary = this.className;
    this.value = Math.max(Math.min(this.value|0, 255), 0) || 0;
    cColor[primary] = hex(+this.value);
    setColor(cColor.r + cColor.g + cColor.b, true);
});

function hex(num) {
    return ("0" + num.toString(16)).slice(-2);
}

// Set default BG color
setColor('000000');
```

Also see [**Colourity Demo**](http://jsbin.com/hogeqeti/5/edit)

Comment: Well what part of the code _actually_ changed the text? Because that's all I need for now

Comment: @user302975 Text color is changed by `document.body.style.color = parseInt(color, 16) > 0xffffff/2 ? 'black' : 'white';`, after the comment `// Change text color`.

Comment: How would I target certain elements? Like only the title in the case

Comment: @user302975 Do you mean only changing the text color of the title? Then, in the code from the previous comment, instead of `document.body` use `document.getElementsByTagName('h2')[0]`. You can also use jQuery if you prefer: `$('h2').css('color', parseInt(color, 16) > 0xffffff/2 ? 'black' : 'white' );`

Comment: Well I also need to change the border at the same time. Could I target multiple things at once?

Comment: @user302975 Using jQuery makes it easier, then. `$('foo, bar').css({color: parseInt(color, 16) > 0xffffff/2 ? 'black' : 'white', border: '1px solid red'} );`

Comment: The border applies to the body for some reason. Here's what I'm using  `$('body, hex').css({color: parseInt(color, 16) > 0xffffff/2 ? 'black' : 'white', border: '3px solid black'} );`

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your hex keyup function like below. So when you enter "000" or "000000" on the hex textbox, the text will become white. if not it will stay in black color.

```
$('.hex').keyup(function () {
var a = $(this).val();
$('#example').text(a);
console.log(a);
$('body').css('background', '#' + a);

  if(a == "000" || a == "000000")
  {
   $('body').css('color','#fff');
  }
  else
  {$('body').css('color','#000');}
function hex2rgb(a) {
  var result = /^#?([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})([a-f\d]{2})$/i.exec(a);
  return result ? {
    r: parseInt(result[1], 16),
    g: parseInt(result[2], 16),
    b: parseInt(result[3], 16)

  } : null;
}

console.log(hex2rgb(a).r);
console.log(hex2rgb(a).g);
console.log(hex2rgb(a).b);


$('.r').val(hex2rgb(a).r);
$('.g').val(hex2rgb(a).g);
$('.b').val(hex2rgb(a).b);

 });
```

[**Fiddle Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshponnukalai/2kRe2/7/)